# Python Regex removing space inside brackets

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm trying to remove spaces surrounding chars inside square brackets, and leave only 1 space outside the square brackets if the next token is a non-whitespace char. For example,
`banana [ pasta pause] [12 haha] [author bird] tree [red] abc [blue]` would be
`banana[pastapause][12haha][authorbird] tree[red] abc[blue]`

It doesn't matter if there's a trailing/leading space or where the space goes left/right. So far I got the space in square down. This is my code for deleting spaces inside:

```
cleaned_texts = []
p = re.compile("\[(\s*?.*?\s*?)\]")
matches = p.findall(orig_text)
for match in matches:
    cleaned = re.sub("\s","",match)
    cleaned_texts.append(cleaned)

text = orig_text
for i in range(len(matches)):
    cleaned = re.sub(matches[i],cleaned_texts[i],text)
    text = cleaned
```

For the adding one space outside if it's in the form `w[]w` with w is a non-space char, I got a very ugly looking version and it still has some corner cases. I'm not sure how to do it efficiently.

```
#find 2 spaces or leading and trailing space
p = re.compile("\s(\[.*?\])\s|\s(\[.*?\])$|^\s?(\[.*?\])\s?")
temp = p.sub(r"\1"," "+cleaned)

#find [] with form a[]b and add a space
p = re.compile("(\S)(\[.*?\])(\S)")
temp_2 = p.sub(r"\1\2"+" "+r"\3",temp)

#find 2 spaces or leading and trailing space one more time
p = re.compile("\s(\[[a-zA-Z-0-9]*?\])\s|^\s?(\[[a-zA-Z-0-9]*?\])\s|\s(\[[a-zA-Z-0-9]*?\])\s?$")
temp_3 = p.sub(" "+r"\1",temp_2)
```

Comment: What if you have `[inside] out side [inside]`?

Comment: @rici It'd be `[inside]out side[inside]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your expected output contains spaces **only** before *tree* and *abc*, but all other spaces (e.g. after *banana* and between `]` and `[`)
disappeared.

This  indicates that you actually want:

1. Delete **all** spaces between brackets.
2. Delete any remaining space (outside brackets) unless there is a **letter**
   after it (not a non-whitespace char).

Notice also that your text contains "paired" brackets, i.e. after `[` (and
a number of non-bracket chars) there occurs `]`, but not another `[` (I want to
make use of this feature).

The patterns to locate both above cases are:

`pat1 = re.compile(r'\s+(?=[^\[]*\])')`

- `\s+` - a sequence of spaces,
- `(?=...)` - followed by (positive lookahead):

  - `[^\[]*` - a possibly empty sequence of chars other than `[`,
  - `\]` - and a closing bracket.

`pat2 = re.compile(r'\s+(?![a-z])', re.I)`

- `\s+` - a sequence of spaces,
- `(?![a-z])` - not followed by a letter (negative lookahead),
- `re.I` - case insensitive.

To do your transformation step by step you can run:

```
t1 = pat1.sub('', orig_text)
print('step 1:', t1)
t2 = pat2.sub('', t1)
print('step 2:', t2)
```

getting:

```
step 1: banana [pastapause] [12haha] [authorbird] tree [red] abc [blue]
step 2: banana[pastapause][12haha][authorbird] tree[red] abc[blue]
```

Or you can do the whole transformation **in one go**, executing:

```
pat2.sub('', pat1.sub('', orig_text))
```

Comment: Lookaround is what I wanted but didn't know too much about it. This makes it easier thanks.